# Countable unions of Vitali sets...

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be sets of positive Lebesgue measure. Let $\Gamma$ be a countable dense subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb{R}$. Consider the partition of $\mathbb{R}$ canonically associated with the equivalence relation $x \in \mathbb{R} \wedge y \in \mathbb{R} \wedge x - y \in \Gamma$. Let $X$ be any selector of this partition. We define an $A, \Gamma$ Vitali set to be $V_{A, \Gamma} = X \cap A$.

My question is can any non-null set be expressed as a countable union of $A, \Gamma$ Vitali sets. i.e. given a set $Y \subset{R}$ such that the Lebesgue measure of $Y$ is not zero, does there exist $A_{i}, \Gamma_{i}$ such that $Y = \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} V_{A_{i}, \Gamma{i}}$?

Comment: The real axis $R$ is presented as the union of countable family of pairwise disjoint Vitali sets  $(A_n)$.  For each $Y$ of positive Lebesgue measure $Y \cap A_n$ is Vitali set. Hence $Y=\cup_{n \in N}(A_n \cap Y)$..

Comment: @Gogi Yes, thank you Gogi, the sets of positive measure case is relatively trivial as you have shown, what I am interested in is the case of non measurable sets.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll have a go at proving this myself.

I think the answer is no.

Proof:

We make use of the following Lemma whose proof can be found [here](http://ki.pwr.edu.pl/cichon/Math/Bernstein.pdf): There exists a partition of the real line into continuum many Bernstein sets.

Consider one of these Bernstein sets, $B$. Then a countable union of translations of $B$ is also non-measurable.

Now suppose $B = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} V_{A_{n}, \Gamma_{n}}$ as in the above question.

Then $\bigcup_{\gamma \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\Gamma_{n}} B \oplus \gamma$ is a countable union of translations of $B$ with infinite measure contradicting the earlier statement.

QED